# Calling a list of df column names to a function based on dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to call a pd.dataframe object but only the objects that are the ones in the key of a dictionary. I have multiple excel template files and they column names vary causing for the need of removal of certain column names. For reproducible reason i attached a sample below.

```
import pandas as pd
 
filename='template'
data= [['Auto','','','']]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['industry','System_Type__c','AccountType','email'])
 
valid= {'industry': ['Automotive'],
        'SME Vertical': ['Agriculture'],
        'System_Type__c': ['Access'],
        'AccountType': ['Commercial']}
 
valid={k:v for k, v in valid.items() if k in df.columns.values}
 
errors= {}
errors[filename]={}
 
df1= df[['industry','System_Type__c','AccountType']]
mask = df1.apply(lambda c: c.isin(valid[c.name]))
df1.mask(mask|df1.eq(' ')).stack()
for err_i, (r, v) in enumerate(df1.mask(mask|df1.eq(' ')).stack().iteritems()):
    errors[filename][err_i] = {"row": r[0],
                               "column": r[1],
                               "message": v + " is invalid check column " + r[1] + ' and replace with a standard value'}
```

I would like df1 to be a variable to a more dynamic list of df.DataFrame objects

**how would I replace this piece of code to be more dynamic?**

```
df1= df[['industry','System_Type__c','AccountType', 'SME Vertical']]
 
#desired output would drop SME Vertical since it is not a df column
df1= df[['industry','System_Type__c','AccountType']]
```

Comment: added a solution, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
# list of the dictionary returns the keys
# you then filter the DF based on it and assign to DF1

df1=df[list(valid)]
df1
```

```
    industry    System_Type__c  AccountType
0   Auto
```